# Impact of fragmentation in Games

Tags: defragment, lag

I'd like to ask, if you install about 15 GB (2 - 3 games) on a system partition (and your pagefile.sys is located on the other drive), could it cause the `fragmentation` to occur in that way, that the **game lags every 2 seconds** and waits for HDD? (e.g. gTA IV )

I don't think it could be my graphics as I have a powerful machine and my gpu chip still has a reserve according to the game itself and performing tools.

Does it mean, that I should **defragment imminent the after install / uninstall**?

**Specs:**

```
Asus G73JH-A1 Notebook
Intel I7 720QM
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870 1GB GDDR5 
2x 7200 RPM 500 GB HDD (Pagefile.sys on the 2nd one at fixes size 1.5 RAM)
8 GB RAM
```

Comment: Any chance of some system specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lag is consistently occurring exactly every 2 seconds then I would say that it may not be simply fragmentation that is causing it, it is more likely a problem somewhere else in the system.

If, at random-ish times, the game lags before certain things like large buildings or new types of car appear then it could point to fragmentation but more generally it could be showing up either overall poor hard drive performance or other system issues.

While it can be beneficial to defragment after an install, on any reasonably modern system I would say that unless the game files are horrifically fragmented into thousands upon thousands of pieces then performance should not be affected by that serious an amount.

Comment: Thank you for your professional answer ! Yes it's definitely a random problem.. and you were right - exactly when new types of car appears or building are to be loaded

Comment: In your reply to AndrejaKo you say that you use Eset Smart Security, I have tried many antivirus packages and they all impact hard drive performance in different ways as they "buffer" the data for virus scanning prior to letting the application use it.  This tends to magnify slow hard drive problems and I've seen systems that are truly crippled by antivirus software. AVG is nice and lightweight and I've not had any problems with it. http://free.avg.com/ . Check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/choosing-anti-anti-virus-software.html

Comment: Yeah, what Mokubai said.  Turn off your antivirus and see if that makes a difference.  It's probably that or simply lousy HDD performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well this depends much on the previous state of your HDD. If it had fragmentation problems before, you would need to defragment it after such an installation. On the other hand, if you didn't have any problems with fragmentation and low disk space before, it's something else. In the end I'd recommend that you do defragment the HDD. You have nothing to lose (leave it working while you sleep for example) and it could solve the problem.

Comment: I recovered the default factory OS from a hidden partition and directly after that I installed about 25 GB  of new games.. and Eset smart security. Nothing more nothing less.. 
But I'll give a try ! thanks